# Ajax request that needs jquery library

Tags: jquery, ajax, qtip

I'm using qTip to load up a modal that, using ajax, displays html/js/css from another file. The content that is being loaded is heavily css/js, and it only works right if I include the jquery javascript file in the content file.

It works fine, but when I close the modal box, none of the other jquery stuff on that page works anymore, like jquery was removed from memory when I closed the modal.

How can I get the ajax content to "share" the original jquery, or at least not remove it when I close it?

Comment: jQuery is only needed once in a page. Standalone version needs it included but loading it via ajax jQuery already exists so you shouldnt need to load it again. Alternative is Iframe

Comment: also worth noting...loading jQUery after other plugins are registered will wipe them out

Comment: Thanks, this was helpful information. I ended up sorting through it and it was a css problem. jquery was indeed only needed once. I think when I added the 2nd jquery, it reset some of the css positioning elements in the new page. When I starting going through the css, I was able to reset some of the items to make it look right.